# How to use cplex or gurobi solver with cvxopt in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, sparse-matrix, cplex, cvxopt

I have a very large linear programming problem (over 10,000 equations and 20,000 variables). The optimization problem is even included in a loop and solved many times. As a result, I want to use sparse matrices with an efficient solver to perform optimization. I know cvxopt can use commercial solvers like Cplex and Gurobi, but do I need a license? How do I call Cplex in cvxopt?

When I use:
solvers.lp(f, Ain, Bin, Aeq, Beq, solver='gurobi')
solvers.lp(f, Ain, Bin, Aeq, Beq, solver='cplex')

The problem can't be solved (shows infeasible). I think that is because I didn't include a license.

I am a student and I have a free Cplex license but don't know how to include it in Python cvxopt.

Here are my codes.

```py
while(1): 
# some code before
    f=matrix(OPT['c1M'].T)
    Ain=sparse_to_spmatrix(OPT['AinM'])
    OPT['Xu']=np.reshape(OPT['Xu'],(len(OPT['Xu']),1))
    OPT['Xd'] = np.reshape(OPT['Xd'], (len(OPT['Xd']), 1))
    Bin=matrix(np.vstack([OPT['BinM'], OPT['Xu'], -OPT['Xd']]))
    Aeq=sparse_to_spmatrix(OPT['AeqM'])
    Beq=matrix(OPT['BeqM'])
    sol = solvers.lp(f, Ain, Bin, Aeq, Beq,solver='glpk',options={'glpk':{'msg_lev':'GLP_MSG_OFF'}})
# some code after
```

Comment: Why go through cvxopt (mostly academic research solvers; minimal modelling support) instead of using the tools of those solvers? Doing it like that, you can control the trade-off between *nice to use* and *fast*.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. cvxopt can consume sparse structures and using a solver then which is not cvxopt (e.g. cplex) leads to copying to those solvers internal structures (which are different). This probably even happens with cvxopt-based solvers. I'm not talkin about cplex studio but cplex' python interfaces. These do not know sparse-matrices, but are built around sparse usage. They are low-lvl (well one is high-lvl and one is low-lvl) and (at least when bound to python) as fast as you can get (basically C-bindings!). No need to leave the python-interpreter!

Comment: ["The CPLEX Python API is a lightweight wrapper around the C API (CPLEX Callable Library"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_20.1.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/Python_setup.html)

Comment: @sascha Thank you sascha. The reason I am using cvxopt is that it supports sparse matrix input. The matrics Ain, Bin is so large (~18000*20000) that it is impossible to use the dense form of them. Cplex and Gurobi API do not seem to support sparse input. If I enter the constraints one-by-one I can foresee it would be much slower.

Comment: You are wrong and should read their docs more carefully! This solvers are expensive as ... and are used at thousands of companies. Do you think they miss out on a simple use case as yours (where they need to recommend the customer to pass through some open-source project)?

Comment: @sacha Thank you very much! I will check out the documents. But I see from other answers that Cplex API does not support sparse matrix input.

Comment: Either those are wrong or you are misinterpreting those. Does it's API know scipy.sparse? No. Does it's API work on sparse concepts? Sure. Do all sane wrappers (like cvxopt, cvxpy, ...) use exactly this API i'm proposing to wrap problems defined with scipy.sparse matrices? YES! There is no way around this. If you start with some scipy.sparse base form like shown in your question (not necessarily the best idea), you could easily build a small wrapper which builds a cplex model in it's python API which will be the *fastest way possible* by using what's available in this API.

Comment: @sacha I agree with you. Cplex itself is good. But I am also thinking that, if it is possible that, Cplex API could convert the input (i.e. constraints) to a sparse form but unable to take sparse matrix as input. Because most people doing optimization like entering constraints one-by-one. Just let me have a try.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229862/discussion-between-zihang-and-sascha).

Comment: There are *most people* (and some with toy demos) and people doing that for a living ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Small example from https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-part2-python-java-c-cc04558e49b5

```
# Import packages.
import cvxpy as cp
# Define and solve the CVXPY problem.
nbBus40 = cp.Variable(integer=True)
nbBus30 = cp.Variable( integer=True)
cost = 500*nbBus40+400*nbBus30
prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cost),[40*nbBus40+30*nbBus30>=300,
                                     nbBus40>=0,nbBus30>=0
                                     ])
prob.solve(solver=cp.CPLEX,verbose=True)
# Print result.
print("\nThe minimal cost is", prob.value)
print("number buses 40 seats = ",nbBus40.value)
print("number buses 30 seats = ",nbBus30.value)
```

Comment: This is not showing anything in regards to cvxopt (and it's not an LP).

Comment: My problem is very large. I will be fine to use cvxpy if the problem can be solved. However, the code you are showing is a very small dense problem. And how to setup Cplex for large problems?

Comment: @Zihang You did not show any code and yet you seem to know everything is too slow. cvxpy is natively working with sparse matrices and it's canonicalization (*the core difference between cvxpy = complex reformulation modelling-tool and cvxopt = solver (+ some modelling)*) should be negligible. If you already got your standard-form as shown in your questions, just post this as algebraic as possible, e.g. `constraints.append(A * x == b)`. cvxpy can be super-slow, yes, because it's doing lots of magic. But that won't happen (be observable) with ready = simple = algebraic = standard-form input.